# Import android.support.design library partially (just ONE component)

Tags: android, android-support-design, gradle-dependencies

I need only one component (`TextInputLayout`) of a library (`android.support.design`). So would be forced to add:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
```

into my project's dependencies and increased the size of my finally `.apk` file, more than expected. **How can I import the only components that are needed**?

Comment: You cannot, but you can use Proguard to strip everything else. Or you create a library project to provide only a shadow of design.

Comment: Option 1) Copy needed classes from design library directly to your project. Option 2) Enable multidex for debug builds, enable proguard for release builds and unneeded classes will not be in your apk anyway.